# How to computer Document Length and Average Document Length in BM25

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval

Please tell me anyone as how to compute document(dl) length and average document length(avdl) in BM25. For example we have the following 4 documents:

```
new york times east // Doc1
los angeles times west //Doc2
washington post district columbia //Doc3
wall street journal north //Doc4
```

Comment: What precisely is your question? In the example, length of each document is 4 and hence the average length is also 4.

Comment: @Debasis But I dont think that length of document is calculated in the way as you mentioned. I think BM25 formula treats length of document in a different way.

Comment: The normal definition of document length applies to BM25 as well, only after removing stopwords and stemming. Another definition of document length could be the number of unique terms present. You could walk through the open source implementation of BM25Similarity in Lucene to know how it's done in Lucene.

Comment: @user3764140 did you get average of document length well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to remove stop-words and perform stemming so that we can consider a document d as a set of constituent terms with corresponding term frequencies {tf(t,d) : t \in d}.

Now, the notion of document length is slightly different in vector space and probabilistic models, e.g. BM25, language model etc. While in the former, document length refers to the norm of a vector, in the latter it typically refers to total number of terms in a document.
Nonetheless, the vector norm notion of documents can, in principle, be also applied to probabilistic models as well because the term frequency values still remain normalized between 0 and 1. However, the normalized term frequency values would no longer sum to 1.

To illustrate with your example: In the case of vector space model, the length is defined as the norm of a vector, which is the case of doc1, is norm(doc1) = square root of the sum of squares of the term frequency values for each unique term in doc1 = sqrt(1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2) = sqrt(4) = 2.

For the probabilistic models, length would be defined as summation of term frequencies of the component terms = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4. The normalized term frequency values of a term t would be P(t,d) = tf(t,d)/dl(d) so that \sum{P(t,d) t \in d} = 1, e.g. 1/4+1/4+1/4+1/4=1.

The BM25Similarity implementation of Lucene uses vector norms as document lengths whereas the Terrier uses sum of tfs of constituent terms as document lengths.

Comment: If I have a document like this "times new new romans". Then how could I compute document length. Either 1 + 1 + 1 and 1/4+1/4+1/4=0.75 OR there is another way?

Comment: tf(times)=1 tf(new)=2 tf(romans)=1  norm(d)=sqrt(1+4+1)=2.44, standard dl (used in probabilistic models) = 1+2+1 = 4

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will help me a lot.